# VB6 post XML (UTF-8) via HTTP

Tags: xml, vb6, xmlhttprequest

i have written visual basic 6 code. It's working well but now i'm posting xml with cyrilic in UTF-8 and other site see different chars. I think because i read and post xml as string. Is there any chance to send them in utf-8?

```
xmlContent()=fs.GetFileContent(Replace(Me.txtOutputFileName.Text, fs.GetFileNameByPath(Me.txtOutputFileName.Text), "") & xmlFileNames(i))
xmlString = MFunctions.GetString(xmlContent())

o.Open "POST", server, False, EE_XML_EXCHANGE_ID, EE_XML_EXCHANGE_PWD

o.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml" ' "text/xml;charset=utf-8"

o.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", ""
o.send xmlString

Me.txtResponseHeaders = o.getAllResponseHeaders
Me.txtResponse = o.responseText
```

Thank you

Comment: Should work as-is as long you you use the right Content-Type.  The .send() method always encodes as UTF-8 when you pass a String.  Why hyperqualify your text boxes with Me and then rely on the default property .Text?  Copy/paste code?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be posting with an explicit label of `charset=utf-8`.  Is that also how the server is serving the data to the other sites that report seeing different characters?